# In what order should a new wordpress theme developer start inspecting the files in default themes?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I've already built a simple theme for my website on Wordpress, but running automated tools like **Theme Checker** showed me my theme doesn't have many important functionalities. After suggestions from many developers on multiple websites, I decided to learn it from the default **TwentyTen** theme.
To the professional developers, in what order should a newbee start inspecting the files in a wordpress theme to maintain the flow and avoid confusions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would rather start by learning from the underscore theme (http://underscores.me/). It is a project made by [Automattic](http://automattic.com/) and is always in development by some of the people who created WordPress. So you are for sure going to learn many of best practises from there.

What theme files to look at first. Start with `index.php`, `page.php` and all the `content-xxx.php` files that are included in various templates. `functions.php` is also very important to grasp as early as possible.